# How to access the group value for each cv iteration in sklearn LeaveOneGroupOut

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some code to validate a model where I'd like to use each year in my data as a hold out set. As such, I am using sklearn [LeaveOneGroupOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut):

```
log_loss_data = [] 
acc_data = []

years = np.arange(df.year.min(),df.year.max()+1)[::-1]

groups = df['year']

X = df[[__my_features__]]
y = df[__my_target__]

logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
logo.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

logo.get_n_splits(groups=groups)

for year, (train_index, test_index) in zip(years, logo.split(X, y, groups)):
  print(f'Leaving out {year}...')

  X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index].copy(), X.iloc[test_index].copy()
  y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index].copy(), y.iloc[test_index].copy()

  model = LGBMClassifier()
  model.fit(X_train, y_train)

  X_test["make_pred"] = (pd.
                         DataFrame(model.predict_proba(X_test),index=X_test.index,columns=[0,"pred"])[["pred"]]
                         )

  log_loss_data.append(log_loss(y_test,X_test["pred"])) 
  acc_data.append(accuracy_score(y_test,np.round(X_test["pred"])))
```

When this is done, I have a list of log loss and accuracy scores for each group. The above code assumes that the order of groups is from greatest to least, but I am unsure if this is the case. I'd like to associate my cv scores with their according group year to see if there's any years (or groups of years/seasonality) that result in different/worse scores. In the docs, it appears as though there are only two methods `.get_n_splits()` and `.split()`. I thought there was for sure a way to access the group value in each cv iteration... Was I incorrect in this assumption?

**EDIT**: I did some testing and it turns out that numeric groups are likely iterated in order from least to greatest. To check this I created two different models. One used the earliest year in my data as a test set and the other used the latest. The respective scores for these models matched the first and last grouped cv iteration scores, respectively. While there is no official documentation (that I have come across) that confirms this, given this test I am quite confident that they are indeed iterated in order from least to greatest.

Comment: Interesting... I too thought there would be a way to access this information from the output of the `split()` method or similar but it doesn't seem to be the case according to the docs. You *could* use the indices from `split()` to find the unique remaining groups from the full dataset but it doesn't seem like a particularly efficient solution for a big dataset...

Comment: Interesting discovery: My scores for the **last** iterated year group in my data actually match the scores from a model I created that used the latest year as the test data. With this info it might be safe to assume that numeric groups are iterated in order from least to greatest, no? I'll make a model that uses the earliest year as a test set now and see if its scores match the **first** iterated group year...

Comment: Well would you look at that. The scores for a model I created that use the earliest year in my data match the scores for the first iterated cv group. Now I would definitely assume it's ordered from least to greatest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you've discovered, the splits happen in the order of group identifiers.

In [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1148--L1154), you can see this: the group array is passed through `numpy.unique`, [which returns the items in order](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), then those are looped over.